# Error fetching row from database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I am trying to fetch a row from a table in my database, and everything is retrieved successfully except for one column (page_content), whose data comes in partially. Here is the table creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE 'usol_site_page' (                                                                                                  
    'page_id' int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,                                                                                     
    'page_type_id' int(11) NOT NULL,                                                                                               
    'page_menu_id' int(11) NOT NULL,                                                                                               
    'page_name' varchar(100) NOT NULL,                                                                                             
    'page_link' varchar(100) NOT NULL,                                                                                             
    'page_heading' varchar(255) default '',                                                                                        
    'page_content' text,                                                                                                           
    'page_title' varchar(255) default NULL,                                                                                        
    'meta_keywords' mediumtext,                                                                                                    
    'keyword_description' text,                                                                                                    
    'pic_small' varchar(255) default NULL,                                                                                         
    'pic_main' varchar(255) default NULL,                                                                                          
    'pic_size' varchar(50) default NULL,                                                                                           
    'pic_type' varchar(50) default NULL,                                                                                           
    'display_order' int(11) NOT NULL,                                                                                              
    'parent_page_id' int(11) NOT NULL,                                                                                             
    'status' varchar(20) NOT NULL,                                                                                                 
    'creation_date' date NOT NULL,                                                                                                 
    'last_update_date' date NOT NULL,                                                                                              
    PRIMARY KEY  ('page_id'),                                                                                                      
    KEY 'Refusol_page_menu60' ('page_menu_id'),                                                                                    
    KEY 'Refusol_page_type44' ('page_type_id'),                                                                                    
    CONSTRAINT 'Refusol_page_menu60' FOREIGN KEY ('page_menu_id') REFERENCES 'usol_page_menu' ('page_menu_id') ON DELETE CASCADE,  
    CONSTRAINT 'Refusol_page_type44' FOREIGN KEY ('page_type_id') REFERENCES 'usol_page_type' ('page_type_id') ON DELETE CASCADE   
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=67 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Does anyone know why page_content is not being fully retrieved?

here is the code the query :

```
$extendQry = "";
            if($mode != "admin"){
                $extendQry = "AND p.status='enable' ";
            }
             $qry = "SELECT p.page_id, p.page_link, p.page_name, p.page_heading, p.page_content, p.status, p.page_title,
                            p.meta_keywords, p.keyword_description, p.pic_main, p.pic_small, p.parent_page_id, 
                            t.page_type_id, t.page_type, m.page_menu_id, m.menu_type
                       FROM usol_site_page p, usol_page_type t , usol_page_menu m
                      WHERE p.page_id = ".$pageId." $extendQry
                        AND t.page_type_id = p.page_type_id 
                        AND m.page_menu_id = p.page_menu_id";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
return mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: my dear where is your select query and code of fetching recod?\

Comment: If the issue lies in fetching the records, we need to see what you have tried to accomplish that.

Comment: If you try to select this column using plain sql? (i.e. from phpmyadmin) it still doesn't fetch whole row?

Comment: In real life terms, you've said you can't close a door in your hose, and provide the blueprints for the house. That doesn't help us see there's a toy stuck in the door, jamming it open...

Comment: Also, if I understand you, which column isn't being fully retrieved?

Comment: i am sorry for being unclear , actually at work where i am currently trapped in this problem here is the code :

Comment: @elegant.rao where is the code again?

Comment: @ Awais Qarni: i have just edited my question with the query that i am executing to fetch the record. :-)

Comment: @Fenec i have tried that in query browser and its giving me the same exact problem. so is there a problem with my query ?

Comment: @elegant.rao my dear again incomplete code. Also give the code of fetching row and you have still not mentioned which columned is not being retrieved...??????????

Comment: @Awais Qarni: my appologies (just don't know how to ask a question :D). i have again edited the question with i believe now , complete information.

Comment: @elegant.rao my dear what happened to you? We are asking about the code where you manupaliting the mysql_fetch_row record?

Comment: define "partially"-what data did you get and what did you expect

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements. Prepare statements will close what may be a potential [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) vulnerability via `$pageId`.

Comment: fellas thank you very much for your quick responce sorry for my very unclear question, i got it solved by changing datatype of the column (page_content) from 'text' (64KB) to mediumtext(16MB). and it is working perfectly now. the forum won't allow me to post my answer so i am posting here. thank you all for your kind support you guyz are the best.

Comment: You can post an answer, but you need to wait 2 days to accept it, and I urge you to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fellas thank you very much for your quick responce sorry for my very unclear question, i got it solved by changing datatype of the column (page_content) from 'text' (64KB) to mediumtext(16MB). and it is working perfectly now. thank you all for your kind support you guyz are the best.